In MS Access I have a formula that works great except when encountering a blank field, then it is returning #error. I just want "". Unsure of syntax
This works well until encountering error:
Proj Lvl2: 
IIf(Len([Project ID])=9,[Project ID],
    Mid$([Project ID],1,InStrRev([Project ID],".")-1))

I've tried adding up front an IIF and ISNumeric but cannot seem to get the syntax correct?
What the formula is doing is if the length of the field is = 9, just use the field value, otherwise take everything left of the second ".".  I would simply use =left but the character lengths between the delimiters varies.  Appreciate any help

After playing around for awhile this seems to have fixed my problem:
Proj Lvl2:
IIf(Len([Project ID])=9 Or Len(Nz([Project ID]))=0,[Project ID],
Mid$([Project ID],1,InStrRev([Project ID],".")-1))
